# Conditions on ratio of $\frac{\sigma_{BIB}^2}{\sigma_{RB}^2}$

Tags: regression, statistical-significance, anova, multivariate-analysis, experiment-design

I'm attempting to solve a question about the variances of random block design versus balanced incomplete block design. I feel I am close to having an answer, but I'm not quite there yet.

Question:

It was previously noted that $\frac{Var_{RB}(\hat{\alpha}_i -\hat{\alpha}_j)}{Var_{BIB}(\hat{\alpha}_i -\hat{\alpha}_j)} = \frac{a(c-1)}{c(a-1)}$, where RB denotes a random block design and BIB denotes a balanced incomplete design. The blocks for a BIB design are likely to be more homogeneous since the block size is smaller than that for an RB design, so we can assume $\sigma_{BIB}^2 < \sigma_{RB}^2$. Find the conditions on the ratio of $\frac{\sigma_{BIB}^2}{\sigma_{RB}^2}$ so that the BIB design will estimate $\alpha_i -\alpha_j$ with greater precision than an RB design.

Attempt:

$\hspace{15mm} \large \frac{2a\sigma_{RB}^2}{N} > \frac{2c(a-1)\sigma_{BIB}^2}{N(c-1)}$

$\hspace{15mm} \large a\sigma_{RB}^2 > \frac{c(a-1)\sigma_{BIB}^2}{(c-1)}$

$\hspace{15mm} \large \sigma_{RB}^2 > \frac{c(a-1)\sigma_{BIB}^2}{a(c-1)}$

$\hspace{15mm} \large \sigma_{RB}^2/ \sigma_{BIB}^2 > \frac{c(a-1)}{a(c-1)}$

I'm not sure where to go from here.

Comment: What do $Var_{RB}(\hat{\alpha}_i)$, $Var_{RB}(\hat{\alpha}_j)$, $Var_{BIB}(\hat{\alpha}_i)$ and $Var_{BIB}(\hat{\alpha}_j)$ equal?